# How do I make Windows 8's Start menu always open applications with "open as new window"?

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

Suppose I am using Notepad for one task, and I want to open up a new Notepad window for another task. When I open Notepad from the Start menu, it simply returns me to the Notepad window I already have open. In order to open up a new Notepad window, I have to right-click on the Start menu's Notepad icon and select "Open as new window".

Is there any way I can make "Open as new window" the default setting? I *always* want to open a new Notepad window, and I *never* want to return to the existing Notepad window (who would???).

Comment: The live tiles on your Start screen are simply an alternate display of the shortcuts in the StartMenu folder. Right-click any live tile and go to its containing folder. Then you'll be able to edit the shortcut's properties. I don't know much about this, but I know there are arguments (starting with a hyphen) you can add to a shortcut's "code" to specify how to launch the program. Probably "new window" is available, yes? Look that up.

Comment: The start menu does not exist on Windows 8 do you happen to mean the start screen? Despite basically the same exact features there are differences. You might need to create a new shortcut that does what you want, and use that, instead of using the current method your using. To expand on Ariane's answer.  I tested the behavior with Windows 7 and the default shortcut in the startmenu does indeed open up a new instance of notepad.  It seems strange if the shortcut is exactly the same ( it is ) this behavior would have changed.

Comment: @Ariane I'm not using (nor am I aware of) any Notepad live tile. I press the Start key, type "notepad", and click on the Notepad icon. Unfortunately, the shortcut associated with the icon does not seem to control the icon's behavior: if I double-click on the shortcut, it always opens as a new window, and yet if I click on the icon, it doesn't open as a new window.

Comment: @Ramhound The shortcut and the icon don't behave the same. See my answer to Ariane.

Comment: @76987 - As I indicate I would simply create your own shortcut. You can pin the shortcut to your taskbar, makes it easy, to launch common application in new instances ( i.e. the calculator ).  Your current method is not opening a new instance for Notepad, because your not using the shortcut, what your doing exactly is hard to put into words.

Comment: @Ramhound If I create my own shortcut, can I put that shortcut in my Start menu? I don't want the hassle of clicking on my taskbar. I want to access Notepad through the Start menu (Start search, whatever it's called).

Comment: @76987 - Of course you can add user created shortcuts to the start screen.  Every single application you install fits that description.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I put my user created shortcut in the same folder as the original Notepad shortcut, but it doesn't show up anywhere in the Start search. I named the shortcut 'qwe', but typing in 'qwe' yields no results.

Comment: @76987 you need to pin it to the menu

Comment: @Ramhound I honestly don't understand what you mean. Which menu do I pin the shortcut to, in order to see it in the Start search?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this guide:

**How to open a new window of a desktop app from the Start screen**

http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-open-a-new-window-of-a-desktop-app-from-the-start-screen/

- Open Registry editor and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell`
- Right click `ImmersiveShell`, and create a new key called `Launcher`.
- At `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher`, right click in the right pane and create a new `DWORD` value called `DesktopAppsAlwaysLaunchNewInstance`.
- Double click it and set its value to `1`.

[image]

- Log off and log in back or just restart Explorer as we showed in this previous post.

That's it. **Now try launching a Desktop app from the Start screen. It will always start a new instance.**

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Win8.1 ENT


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher]
"DesktopAppsAlwaysLaunchNewInstance"=dword:00000001


WinKey+cmd+enter - Command windows opens
WinKey+cmd+enter - Takes me to the command window that's already open.

Comment: this works in Win8.0. I have no idea if it works in 8.1 or not.

Comment: Wait....does this ONLY work for Start tiles?  Is it supposed to also work for searched apps from the search bar?  For me, it only works when clicking on tiles.

Comment: I never use the startscreen or the Search so I can't help. I prefer the old Win7 Startmenu from StartIsBack.